# Validity of a statistical procedure to calculate an odds ratio for a Fisher's exact test?

Tags: regression, odds-ratio, fishers-exact-test, validity, overfitting

I am trying to determine whether this is a valid statistical procedure.

I have ~1000 samples, and each sample has around 1-500 data points. Each data point consists of two fractions (value1 and value2) that range from 0 to 1. I am trying to perform a fisher's exact test with the two fractions (I have the numerator and denominator for each fraction in a 2x2 table) to test for their equality. However, in examining the data, I found that, in general, the fractions are not equal, but rather value2 is frequently greater than value1. In order to correct for this, I want to modify my Fisher's exact test by changing the odds ratio to reflect this modified null hypothesis.

In my setup, this odds ratio should not change within a sample. I think the modified odds ratio should be the expectation for the ratio of value2/value1 within each sample. One way to obtain this ratio is to simply perform a regression of value2 on value1 (for each sample). I perform this regression through the origin because data points with value1=0 must also have value2=0. Then, using the slope of this regression, I would have a new value for the expected ratio (value2/value1) for each sample, and I could use this as the odds ratio in my fisher's exact test. (Note that some samples have only 1-5 data points, so regression of value2 on value1 is problematic, but I can estimate the slope of the regression by finding similar samples).

My question is, would this procedure be statistically valid? It seems like this may be a case of overfitting. Also, I am not sure whether it is reasonable to use the data so much before performing my statistical test. However, I think that this is essentially a test for outliers, so it seems valid to use the entire data set.